# need a rasp PI5 debian linux host connected to netcomm NF18 router then to ISP, to 'see' a host on another LAN

Tags: networking

LAN 1 : netcomm NF18 router ( 192.168.20.1 )facing the ISP modem
Raspberry Pi5 debian linux --> 192.168.20.3 on netcomm router
LAN 2 : tplink TP-WR841N router ( 192.168.1.1 ) --> netcomm router lan cable to WAN port on
netcomm router
LAN 2 can see & connect to LAN 1 host 192.168.1.110 for camera access via browser

Problem : LAN 1 ( 192.168.20.0/24 ) also needs to see the camera on LAN 2.
Why ? because I have a 'no-ip' ddns public access setup to run a flask app on 192.168.1.0/24.
Note: netcomm router ( LAN1 192.168.20.1 ) has port '2020' ( camera ) forwarded to 192.168.1.110 on LAN 2 to support a flask app that runs the camera videos.
I've tried all sorts of ip route add tests on 192.168.20.0/24 but only get traceroute & ping timeouts trying to get access to the 192.168.10/24 LAN.
UFW is disabled or Illegal gateway.

Bottom Line :- this needs to have 2 different LAN's talking :- 192.168.20.0/24 <-> 192.168.1.0/24 but I'm getting nowhere ?
Apps and stuff on LAN 2 are happily going out to LAN 1 thence to the 'net but I cannot get routing to work back the other way.
Can you please tell me what I am missing ?

Comment: Your question need reformatting to be understood. I wouldn't reformat it myself because I think there's a discrepancy with "LAN 2 can see & connect to LAN 1 host 192.168.1.110", but 192.168.1.110 should be in LAN 2, not LAN 1. Once resolved, you will have to tell us where NAT is applied or not. The only place where NAT *has to* be applied is on the device with a WAN IP address (I'm not even sure which one it is if any). If there's NAT elsewhere else, this turns a simple setup that should work into a difficult setup where bandaid has to be applied in several places.

Comment: Also remember UL SE is about Unix/Linux. That means configuring "netcomm NF18 router"  or "tplink TP-WR841N" (unless running OpenWRT or equivalent) is off-topic here, but might be on-topic on Superuser (check their on-topic help: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic ).  But if you don't improve the question first, it won't help any better.